# SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, windows-authentication

I'm totally new to Windows programming.

I wish to connect to a SQL Server that utilizes AD authentication. All we need is a simplest possible  command line utility to fetch some data and dump it to a text file. Can I use VBScript for this/any-other-simple-script?

My first preference was to use Perl on Unix. Tried `dbi:Sybase`, doesn't seem to work :(.

TIA.

Edit: I don't have admin privs so my options are pretty limited. Cannot install Python.

Comment: Can you install Powershell or do you have it already installed? It's into the standard Windows Server distribution

Comment: @abatishchev. Yes we have PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple "script" try out python pymssql:

 http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/

 available for windows python 2.4 , 2.5 , 2.6:

 http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymssql/files/pymssql/1.0.2/

 just install it and check out the samples: 

 http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/examples_pymssql.php

Answer (score 0):

Googling by keywords `powershell` + `sql server` + `windows authentication` gives several solutions:

- http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1947
- http://www.powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aff/24/aft/4540/afv/topic/Default.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg313741.aspx
- [etc](http://www.google.com/search?q=Windows+Authentication+sql+server+powershell)